How to create a curved line?
How to make a border like this?
I have followed this tutorial, but have not found a way to achieve the picture I attached. How can I make it like that?
I've tried using image/svg for the curve, but it doesn't look good on responsive.



body {
 background:pink;
}
.box {
  height:150px;
  margin:10px 0;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
  --l:3px;  /* Thickness of the curve */
  --r:90px; /* The curve radius */
  --w:60%;  /* The width of the left part (i.e distance of the curve from the left) */
  --c:red;  /* Color of the curve*/
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  height:calc(50% - var(--l)); /* each one will take half the height minus border width*/
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:var(--c);
}
/* Left part */
.box:before {
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   width:var(--w);
   border-width:0 var(--l) var(--l) 0; /* Right & Bottom*/
   border-radius:0 0 var(--r) 0; /* Bottom-right*/
}
/* Right part*/
.box:after {
   top:0;
   right:calc(-1 * var(--l)); /* Move slightly to the right to have a perfect join */
   width:calc(100% - var(--w));
   border-width:var(--l) 0 0 var(--l); /* Top & Left */
   border-radius:var(--r) 0 0 0; /* Top-Left*/
}
<div class="box"></div>




I would simply use a SVG. Far easier.

Can you show us the svg that you tried and describe what isn’t working?

I would use an SVG using the attribute vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" to ensure that the stroke (border) doesn’t scale with the shape.


body {
  background: #444;
  margin: 1em;
}

svg {
  width: 50%;
}

path {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: red;
}
<svg viewBox="-5 -5 210 110">
  <path d="M 0 0 C 0 0 82.776 -0.027 83.672 0 C 87.981 0.13 90.644 0.921 93.125 3.125 C 93.801 3.726 105.917 15.94 106.836 16.836 C 108.651 18.605 111.218 20.022 115.625 20 C 116.413 19.996 200 20 200 20 L 200 100 L 0 100 L 0 0 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>  
</svg>



After running this snippet, use the full page link to properly test the responsive behaviour.
Or use it as a background to another element.


body {
  background: #444;
  margin: 1em;
}

svg {
  width: 50%;
}

path {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: red;
}

.d1 {
  color: white;
  padding: 15vw 2em 2em;
  aspect-ratio: 20 / 7;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-5 -5 210 110'%3E%3Cpath d='M 0 0 C 0 0 82.776 -0.027 83.672 0 C 87.981 0.13 90.644 0.921 93.125 3.125 C 93.801 3.726 105.917 15.94 106.836 16.836 C 108.651 18.605 111.218 20.022 115.625 20 C 116.413 19.996 200 20 200 20 L 200 100 L 0 100 L 0 0 Z' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke' style='fill: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2px; stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<div class="d1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed.
</div>



